# How to simulate location on iOS simulator when offline?

Tags: ios, location, mkmapview, ios-simulator

I want to simulate location on iOS simulator when I'm offline without internet connection.

I created an iOS application which contains a `MKMapView`, and I set:

```
MKMapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow
```

To show my location in Simulator. To fix the location for debugging, I defined a customize location in Simulator. It works fine when I'm online. But when I'm offline, the Simulator cannot show the customized location, but keep printing the following message in console. How to fix that?

Failed to get location shift function:

`Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0xae83fb0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp13-cn.ls.apple.com/shift, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp13-cn.ls.apple.com/shift, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}`

Comment: I think it's not about the location, that doesn't work but the error occurs, because simulator can't fetch the map graphics from the server. They aren't stored in the simulator or app; they reside on Apple's servers.

Comment: OK. But how to solve that? How can I mock the Apple's service to let simulator receive information. Actually, I don't care about the map graphics and location shift. I just want the MKMapView to trigger mapView didUpdateUserLocation: in offline mode after I set MKMapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow

Comment: Use only `CLLocationManager` - without a map.

Answer (score 0):

SAE is correct. To be clear: the map should be showing a blue dot indicating your simulated location but the error message refers to the fact that the map surrounding the location cannot be viewed because mapView isn't able to download the required information (i.e. map tiles).